# react - tailwind hover showing only on last slide, not all

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I have problem with slider in react.
In line 32, I have hover background for each slide, but hover working only on last slide, why?
[- url for stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-9zzxac?file=src/components/Slider/SliderContent.jsx)

I trying everything, I spend on this 3 hours, what is wrong?

Comment: You should include your code in the question and I shouldn't answer that, but it doesn't work, because `bg-orange` doesn't exist

Comment: bg-orange is default tailwind.

Comment: For some reason, some of your classes are not included in the final css file. Your slide should have a color before hovering, but it doesn't. Changing `orange` to `blue` or `red` fixes the issue

Comment: No, when I change color name from bg-orange, on bg-red, not helping. If you comment in data.js second slide, first with bg-orange, working normally.

Comment: p.s I setup 2x red,and first slide is not working.

Comment: Seems like the CDN version of tailwind doesn't include orange. Using CDN for tailwind is a pretty bad idea anyways, you should use PostCSS or some other solution https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/installation#using-tailwind-via-cdn

Comment: @ShamPooSham 
please look at now I set 2x red, but in first slider, hover not working, in second working, what is wrong?
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-9zzxac?file=src%2FApp.js

Comment: Your hover doesn't work, becuase your second slide is obscuring the first one. You can replace `opacity-0` with `opacity-0 pointer-events-none` and hover will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. As I can see, you built a custom slider which is a good thing. But here, the other slides are actually layered relatively on top of each other. Which means the last slide will always be at the top of the stack even if the opacity is 0. I thought of using z-index to control it but I think this is even cleaner:

```
<div key={key} className={`absolute inset-0  transition duration-500 ease-in-out ${activeIndex === parseInt(key) ? 'visible opacity-100' : 'invisible opacity-0'}`}>
```

I modified **Line 23 in SliderContent.jsx** such that, if the current block is not active slide, add Tailwind's 'invisible' class so it pops it from the top of layer and user can hover successfully.

Tried it, it worked. Goodluck :)